# Fitting multiple nls functions with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to fit multiple nls functions using a `group_by` from the `dplyr` package but I am unsure how I can pass multiple starting values. Let's take a simpler example (see `?nls` for the inspiration).

```
DNase1 <- subset(DNase, Run == 1)
modelDNase1 <- DNase1 %>% 
  do(model = nls(density ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - log(conc))/scal)),
             data = .,
             start = list(xmid = 0, scal = 1),
             algorithm = "plinear"))
```

So here I am fitting a single model. But what if I want to extend this so I am fitting the following:

```
DNase$Run <- factor(DNase$Run)
modelDNase <- DNase %>%
  group_by(Run) %>% 
  do(model = nls(density ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - log(conc))/scal)),
             data = .,
             start = list(xmid = 0, scal = 1),
             algorithm = "plinear"))
```

How would I pass on multiple `start` parameters? Would the `purrr` package be of any use?

Comment: Could you add the starting values by group to your data frame and then do something like `start = list(xmid = .$xmid[1]...)`?

Comment: Hmm I don't think so. The data are in long format (see `data(DNase, package = "datasets")`)

Comment: Let me rephrase: If you add the starting values to the data frame (repeated constants within each group), I think you could use the approach suggested in my first comment. I'm not sure that the `.$` syntax will work, it may be a syntax problem. If your column is called `xmid`, you could probably even just do `start = list(xmid = xmid[1], ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Comment to answer.) My first guess was correct, the `.$` syntax seems to work.

As a convenient way of picking starting values, create a table with the unique group values and the desired starting values in new columns. Knowing nothing about this data, I assigned them randomly:

```
starts = data.frame(Run = unique(DNase$Run),
           xmid_start = rnorm(11, sd = 0.1),
           scale_start = 1 + rnorm(11, sd = 0.1))
```

We can then join this to the data and proceed, pulling the first starting value from each grouping to give to the model:

```
mods = DNase %>% 
    left_join(starts) %>%
    group_by(Run) %>%
    do(model = nls(density ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - log(conc))/scal)),
             data = .,
             start = list(xmid = first(.$xmid_start),
                          scal = first(.$scale_start)),
             algorithm = "plinear"))
```

Comment: This is quite a neat solution. Thanks. I will leave it open to see if there are any other ways, but otherwise I am reasonably happy with this.